# Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to execute my hive from command prompt.
When i am trying to run the command on my Windows 10 machine.
i.e C:\hadoop-2.7.1\hive-2.1.0\bin>hive

It throws the **Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration** Error.

Here is full Stack of Error:

```
Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: Couldn't create directory ${system:java.io.tmpdir}\${hive.session.id}_resources
```

What could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `namenode` and `datanode` services are running. Start those by `sbin/start-dfs.cmd` on windows.